get all commits of a branch already merged into parent branch
My git repo timeline looks something like this : 


After merging the feature-A branch into main branch [commit K], I want to log all the commits that are only part of feature-A branch [commits B, I and J].
And adding in to the 1st point, what if I want to exclude the merge commits like commit I.

Also, why does dot operator give blank output when trying this command : git log main..feature-A

You're looking for --exclude-first-parent-only main..feature-A, all commits in feature-A's history that aren't in main's first-parent history.
The plain main..feature-A you tried is all commits in feature-A's history that are not in main's history—but feature-A is in main's history, so there's nothing to list.
--no-merges doesn't list any merges.

git log --exclude-first-parent-only main..feature-A while checked out in feature-A branch, still does not list anything

can fast forward merge be the reason behind why I m still seeing blank list of commits, when I try git log --exclude-first-parent-only main..feature-A ?

@humbleCodes Fast-forwards are not merges. Fast-forwards don't leave traces in the commit tree so there is no way to traverse (or skip) over them.

@humbleCodes If feature-A is in main's first-parent ancestry, yes. In the history you asked about, it isn't.
